# What happens when an event occurs while program is working

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question regarding events in c#. What happens when program is working (for example a loop is executed and it takes a couple of minutes to finish) and an event occurs ( for example FileSystemWatcher will call "created" event ).

Event will be ignored?
FSW will not call the event, so creating new file will be ignored?
The code which has to be executed when event occurs will be executed after the loop ends?

Of course loop has nothing to do with this event, and no background workers or so are used.

Comment: Callbacks create their own thread, so the main calculation will not be interrupted, but you can call a routine to deal with whatever event you observed.

Comment: FSW calls the events on a separate thread

Comment: FSW has a SynchronizingObject property.  It completely changes the way it works.  Instead of randomly starting another thread to tell you what happened, leaving it up to you to deal with the consequences of that, it will force FSW to wait until you are ready to receive the notification.   Later, when you are *not* busy doing something else.  Much, much easier to deal with.  But with strings attached, make sure that event doesn't fire too often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends a lot on the implementation. In the case of `FileSystemWatcher` I would expect that event to be raised on a worker thread *created by the system* - so it will happen concurrently with the loop. If it was a UI event, I would expect it to be appended to the message loop's queue, to be processed *after* any work currently blocking the UI thread (which you shouldn't do). It would be unusual for an event to just disappear into nowhere unless that was a deliberate design feature - which seems unlikely.

In the case of many other events that are caused by regular code - they are usually processed synchronously *when encountered*.

So we have 3 options:

- processed synchronously by the causing thread
- invoked on a worker thread
- added to the UI thread's queue (typically via "sync-context")

In this case, I believe the answer is "invoked on a worker thread", but all 3 are possible for events more generally